# Formatting dates in python datasframe to be in a m/d/Y

Tags: python, pandas

I tried doing this based on what I found online

```
df['CutoffDate'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df['CutoffDate']), format="%m/%d/%Y")
df.head()
```

And I get this

[image]

What I want is 6/30/2019

Comment: The `format` parameter specifies the input string format, so that `pandas` can successfully convert it to the `datetime64` dtype. Any additional formatting with `.strftime` turns it back to a string, and you lost a lot of functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `strftime`

```
pd.to_datetime(df['CutoffDate']).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```